# Динамические related_name. Как узнать?

Tags: django

У меня есть модель-родитель:

```
class INote(models.Model):                                                               

    Content = models.TextField(verbose_name=u'содержание')
    Time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=u'Время')
    From = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name = '%(class)s')
```

И потомок:

```
class Article(INote):
    pass
```

Я наследуюсь через мультитэйбл (не абстрактно).

При этом я хочу сохранить related_name для потомка, чтобы мог к нему обращаться из связанной модели согласно [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance%23model-inheritance).

Согласно документации related_name для Article должно принять вид `articles`, но по факту работает только `inote`. Во всех остальных случаях получаю `has not attribute`. Вероятно, потому, что модель родителя не является абстрактной. Возможно ли как-либо динамически назначать related_name для потомков неабстрактной модели?

Comment: `article_set` тоже не работает

Comment: Может быть, я что-то не так делаю, поправьте меня пожалуйста

Comment: Хотя сейчас перечитал перевод на djbook, и пришел к выводу, что для наследования от неабстрактных моделей эта конструкция тоже должна работать, но у меня почему-то нет..

Comment: Немного не так, `%(class)s` должен дать `article` без `s` в конце

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name

Comment: @digital-mag , вероятно, вы правы о том, что шаблон %(class)s применяется только к потомкам абстрактной модели. В любом случае в документации сказано конкретно про них. 

Я бы предложил вам как решение использовать related_name='articles' дочерней модели, переопределив внешний ключ как parent_link=True в OneToOneField(). Таким образом, мне кажется, вы сможете обращаться как-то в духе Profile.objects.get(id=_id).inotes.articles